# How can I configure the camera app to disable mirroring?

Tags: release-loki, settings, camera

I want to use camera app just for preview. Actualy I am using a microscope camera for inspecting small objects. So I do not want it to mirror the object. How can I disable this feature?

Regards,
Zsolt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Camera app is hardcoded to always flip video. It utilises [GStreamer's videoflip filter](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videoflip.html) with a hardcoded value for the flip method.

If you must use the Camera app, you can disable this by cloning the code and compiling from source. You can comment out [this line](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/snap-elementary/snap/view/head:/src/Widgets/CameraView.vala#L73) and then compile and install.

An alternative which doesn't use the native Camera app, is to install [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) and disable the 'Horizontal Flip' effect.